# Object won't move even with velocity -Unity-

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I got the problem that my object won't move when I apply a velocity in.

```
Rigidbody2D Rigidb;
float MovingSpeed = 5f;

void Awake()
{
    Rigidb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void MoveObject(Vector3 destination)
{
    Vector3 dirVector = destination - transform.position;

    bool x = false, y = false;

    if (dirVector.x < 0)
    {
        x = true;
        dirVector.x = -dirVector.x;
     }
     if (dirVector.y < 0)
     {
         y = true;
         dirVector.y = -dirVector.y;
     }

     if (dirVector.x > dirVector.y)
     {
         dirVector = dirVector / dirVector.x;
     }
     else
     {
         dirVector = dirVector / dirVector.y;
     }

     if ((x && dirVector.x > 0) || (!x && dirVector.x < 0)) dirVector.x = -dirVector.x;
     if ((y && dirVector.y > 0) || (!y && dirVector.y < 0)) dirVector.y = -dirVector.y;    
     Rigidb.velocity = new Vector2(dirVector.x * MovingSpeed, dirVector.y * MovingSpeed);
}
```

In my testcases the velocity ends up being (0.0, 5.0) but even though it just won't move. It isn't kinematic and the x and y movement isn't frozen either.

Comment: 1) Are you sure Rigidbody is attached (it would throw an error if it wasnt tho), 2) Is MoveObject called? 3) I would like to see a Debug.Log right after the very last line where you are assigning Rigidb.velocity, can you share what value velocity has.

Comment: It is called and the Rigidbody is attached. Also the velocity is (0.0, 5.0) just as it should be) even when I check in the unity inspector while running it shows that velocity. But it doesn't move...

Comment: You are not even calling `MoveObject`? Where and how are you calling that?

Comment: Sry that part in the method actually is part of a larger method and is used per if-command. But the rest of the actual method is just calculation and observation and doesn't affect any part of the GameObject, at least when the object isn't moving

Comment: Would be easier to tell what's the problem if you give us the Debug.Log message of velocity you have set.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have your rigidbody isKinematic to false, and position constraint to not freeze to x,y,z axis